# Laravel OG Image

Tags: facebook, laravel

I am using public_path('website.jpg') to render the og:image meta data, however im not sure that it is working as facebook still is not using the image specified. Is this correct?

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/var/www/website/public/website.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public_path()` function returns the absolute file path. Instead, you should use the `url()` function.